# Changes in Array2 has influence on Array (tables)

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a little problem with my tables.

```
    int najmniejszy_dzielnik(int m){
                cout<<"Array["<<m<<"] = "<<Array[m]<<endl;
                return Array[m];
    }

    int* czynniki_pierwsze(int m){
            int temp, size, i, helper;
            for(temp=m, i=1; 1 < temp; i++){
                helper=najmniejszy_dzielnik(temp);
                cout<<"test1, array[5] = "<<Array[5]<<endl;

                Array2[i]=helper; //------------------------------problem here
                cout<<"test2, array[5] = "<<Array[5]<<endl;

                temp/=helper;
                cout<<"test3, array[5] = "<<Array[5]<<endl;

                }
                Array2[0]=i;
                return Array2;
    }
```

This code was giving me wrong results, so I created cout "test1", "test2" and "test3", and I have found out this:

```
Array[225] = 3
test1, array[5] = 5
test2, array[5] = 5
test3, array[5] = 5
Array[75] = 3
test1, array[5] = 5
test2, array[5] = 3
test3, array[5] = 3
```

Changing value in `Array2[i]` has influence on `Array[ ]`.

How did it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this influence was using the same stack by Array[ ] and Array2[ ].
I should have used pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
    for(temp=m, i=1; 1 < temp; i++)
```

Did it mean:

```
    for(temp=m, i=1; i < temp; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code seems doesn't have any issues. Please check here http://codepad.org/igdzwNnE. May be outside function edits the 'Array' at same time